# How can pass my data into this particular serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working with data that looks like:

```
{ "events": [] }
```

But, I'd like to transform it to:

```
{ "events":
     "added-to-calendar": [],
     "confirmed": []
 }
```

I've written out a serializer that looks like:

```
class CalendarFeedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """ Serializer for the Calendar Feed """

    added_to_calendar = EventSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    confirmed = EventSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

But, I'm not entirely sure how to pass my data into this Serializer.

Here's the `ListAPIView` that I am working with to achieve `{ "events": [] }`:

```
class CalendarFeedView(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.EventSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        added_to_calendar_events = user.events_in_calendar()
        confirmed_events = user.events_confirmed()
        return added_to_calendar_events | confirmed_events
```

But, as you can see, I am using the base EventSerializer that I created to transform this list of Event's. What I want, is to somehow pass `added_to_calendar_events` and `confirmed_events` to my `CalendarFeedSerializer` so that I can have the desired data structure

```
{ "events":
     "added-to-calendar": [],
     "confirmed": []
 }
```

Comment: Can you please share your `models.py` file ?

Comment: Can you please also share your `serializers.EventSerializer` implementation? Is there a reason you've set the `serializer_class` for `CalendarFeedView` to `serializers.EventSerializer` instead of `serializers.CalendarFeedSerializer`, or is that a typo?

Comment: `serializer_class` is currently set to `serializers.EventSerializer` because that's what's providing me with `{ "events": [] }`. Simply changing the `serializer_class` to `serializers.CalendarFeedSerializer` doesn't give me the output of `{ "events":
     "added-to-calendar": [],
     "confirmed": []
 }` which is what I hope to achieve. I'm not sure how to provide my data to `serializers.CalendarFeedSerializer`.

Comment: @xxnora I'm not entirely sure how the model impacts the serialization. I'd prefer to keep that code away simply to keep this post a bit cleaner and to the point.
@Derek I've specified the `serializer` questions above.